# Spring Security ignore few urls few urls basic auth remaining all JWTTokenAuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In my application, i need to implement different spring securities based on different URL. for /app/healthcheck need to ignore security, for /app/manage need to have basic authentication, for remaining all other /api/** need JWT Token authentication. Implemented like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter defaultConfig() {
        return new WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                configureHttpSecurity(http.csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable().and(),
                        authenticationManager());
            }
        };
    }
    void configureHttpSecurity(HttpSecurity http, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app/healthcheck").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new MyJWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .logout().permitAll();

    }
    @Bean
    public UserAuthenticationProvider springAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new UserAuthenticationProvider();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class BasicSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.cors();
        http.antMatcher("/app/manage")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

in application.yml added

spring:
  profiles: dev
  security:
    user:
      name: ${admin}
      password: ${password}
```

when i run the app, /app/healthcheck ignoring security, remaining all other asking for JWT authentication. but /app/manage also triggering JWT authentication instead of basic auth. If i comment Token auth, basic is working perfect.

am new to spring security please let me know what am i missing.

Thank You.

Comment: It might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57058939/how-to-configure-multiple-security-contexts-in-spring-boot/57060379#57060379

Comment: Why is your `WebSecurityConfig ` so complicated? Just write it like your `BasicSecurityConfig`. Did you expose your `MyJWTAuthenticationFilter` also as a bean?